# OAuth in Jira - 'consumer_key_unknown' while requesting token

Tags: oauth, jira

I am trying to connect to Jira using OAuth. I have followed [this](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian_tutorial/atlassian-oauth-examples/src/d625161454d1?at=default) manual and I have created app link in Jira instance and configured it with proper consumer key and public key. When I try to request a token using code from the example I am getting 401 with following message (same for python and perl instance):

```
oauth_problem=consumer_key_unknown
```

I am out of ideas what can be wrong. I will appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I believe that I have configured Application link in the wrong place. I have been somehow navigated to the link `wiki/admin/listapplicationlinks.action`. Then I accidentally found `plugins/servlet/applinks/listApplicationLinks` which looked pretty much the same as first but content was different. I have added link to the second location and everything works well now. 
Sorry for confusion.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. But not able to figure out what the actual problem is. Can you please provide some example on how you did the configurations? I am using java for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this similar error. So I then used different "consumer key"(tried to make this unique) other than the given one in the example manual. After searching a lot in internet about this error, I got to know that as most people are using that same consumer key(given in example manual), a database error occurred due to which this error was thrown.